# Windows Server Shares web interface?

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-attached-storage, network-share

At work and home, I use Server 2003 with Windows Shares. We also have a couple of Netgear ReadyNAS appliances at work, managed via the web interface.

Is there a built-in Web Interface for managing Shares, or a free one available - for use in Server 2003 (or 2008)?

The reason I ask is that it would be good to manage the Shares via the Web, rather then RDP onto the Server each time - and would allow other users to treat it as a NAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a native Web interface for managing Windows shares (not sure that's a good idea anyways).  I'm not sure what you need to "manage" all the time -- usually a share is setup once and used from that point on without much "management".

If you like the idea of a Web-based method of accessing file shares, you may want to look at installing Sharepoint Services and you can setup (and authenticate against Active Directory) document libraries between users, groups, etc. that are all accessible via Internet Explorer internally or externally, depending on how the Sites are configured.

Comment: Thanks for the Sharepoint idea. Looks like we'll stick to setting up Shares as normal using the GUI on the Server itself.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in web interface for managing shares. It's a simple enough matter to use remote computer management. i.e. Log in with an account the remote machine will recognise as having admin access. Open Computer Manager on the client and then connect to the remote machine. All shares are readily managed from there.